# Неясные клоны приложений facebook и messenger

Tags: android

Обнаружил на андроиде "клоны" приложений facebook и messenger. В информации о них нет нету пункта "О приложении в магазине". На иконках какие-то кольца снизу справа. Гугл ничего не говорит, возможно из-за того, что не совсем понятно, что гуглить. Что это такое? Причем клон facebook также нельзя удалить как обычное приложение facebook, а только остановить (facebook был встроен в ОС похоже).  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: можно перейти в настройки клонирования приложений и удалить клоны

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/galaxys10/comments/b38zcz/what_is_this_orange_badge_with_two_rings/ - 10 секунд в гугле. Присоединяюсь к первому ответу